# Construction of a positive function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I wanted to build a positive  function $r:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:r(x,y)=0\}=Gr(\frac{1}{x})$, that is, only cancels on the graph of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. It was suggested here in Mathexchange $r(x,y)=(xy-1)^2$. But this function also cancels in the set $\{(-x,-\frac{1}{x}): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Since the set that you mention *is* the graph of the function $f$, what's your problem?

Comment: $-Gr(f)=\{(-x,-\frac{1}{x}):x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: And $-\operatorname{Gr}(f)=\operatorname{Gr}(f)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is right. Note that the set $\{(-x,-\frac{1}{x}): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is part of $Gr(\frac{1}{x})$.

Setting $t=-x$ you have
$$
\{(-x,-\frac{1}{x}): x \in \mathbb{R}\}=\{(t,\frac{1}{t}): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want $f$ to vanish on $\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid xy=1,x>0\right\}$, so try 
$$f = \begin{cases}(xy-1)^2 & x\geq0 \\ (xy-1)^2 +e^{-1/x} & x<0\end{cases}$$

This is infinitely differentiable, and can only be zero if $x>0$ and $xy=1$.